# Show that the new system $e_0, e_1, e_2, ...$ is an orthonormal set in $C_p (a,b)$

Tags: analysis, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

I'm confused about this question and I can't find anything helpful anywhere...

My question is as follows:

> A set of functions
> $$
> \phi_0,\phi_1, \phi_2, ..., \phi_n
> $$
> is said to be linearly independent if any linear combination of the form
> $$
> a_0\phi_0+a_1\phi_1+a_2\phi_2+...+\phi_n=0
> $$
> imply that the numbers $a_0, ... a_n$ are all zero for any chosen $n \geq 1$. Now suppose that $f_0, f_1, f_2, ...$ is a linearly independent system in $C_p(a,b)$. Define a new system of functions $e_0, e_1, e_2, ...$ as follows:
> $$
> g_0=f_0 \phantom{1333331133333333333333333} e_0=\frac{g_0}{||g_0||}
> $$
> $$
> g_1=f_1- \frac{\langle f_1, g_0\rangle}{||g_0||^2}g_0 \phantom{11111111111111}e_1=\frac{g_1}{||g_1||}
> $$
> $$
> g_2 = f_2 - \frac{\langle f_2, g_1\rangle}{||g_1||^2}g_1 -\frac{\langle f_2, g_0\rangle}{||g_0||^2}g_0 \phantom{111}  e_2=\frac{g_2}{||g_2||}
> $$
> show that the new system $e_0, e_1, e_2, ... $ is an orthonormal set in $C_p(a, b)$

My confusion lies in how you show something is an orthonormal set. I get I need to use induction but yeah that's as much as I understand needs to be done. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show that they have unit length. Show that $\langle e_i, e_j \rangle = 0$ for $i < j$.

Comment: that's another thing like i don't know what that means. Like sorry I know this is stupid but I've only ever seen those used for like vectors and stuff, and I'm super confused as to what that notation means (the inner product i think it's called; i could be wrong). How do you show it's 0?

Comment: The inner product satisfies certain properties, you need to use those.

Comment: okay wait i've seen the inner product defined as simply multiplication but i've also seen it defined as some kind of integral over a given interval: $\int_{a}^{b} e_i e_j $

Comment: You don't need to know how it is defined. You just need to know its properties. Like linear (or conjugate linear - I don't know what you have been taught),

Comment: I think the definition of $g_2$ is missing something. This is the Gram Schmidt process..

Comment: you're right it is missing something editing it now. sorry about that. EDIT: fixed $g_1$ and $g_2$ bc they were missing things

Comment: You know the $e_k$s are normalised versions of the $g_k$. So it is sufficient to show that $\langle g_i, g_j \rangle  = 0$ for $i < i$. Just try $\langle g_0, g_1 \rangle$ to start.